# RVM's current and default version isn't actually being used

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

I am running my rails app from a virtualbox build by vagrant using puppet scripts. Every time I login to the box, I have the following problem:
When I run `rvm list` one of the things it lists is the following:

```
=* ruby-2.1.1
```

But when I try to run `rails console`, it tells me I need to install missing gems. When I run `rvm use default`, and then run `rails console`, it works. Why is the default and current setting in rvm not working--why do I have to go to the extra step of also telling rvm which ruby version to use?

Note: I do have a .ruby-version file with 2.1.1 in it. I'm using rvm version 1.25.25

Answer (score 0):

Because you have to tell rvm which version to use.

In earlier version of rvm we have to define .rvmrc file which mention which ruby and gemset to use.

In recent version of rvm we have to define .ruby-version file with ruby version in it and .ruby-gemset file with the name of gemset.

If you just want a quick solution then in your rails directory make a .ruby-version file with content `2.1.1`

Comment: I already had a .ruby-version file with the correct ruby version (I updated my question to specify this), but it still wasn't working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

correct syntax is:

rvm --default use ruby-2.1.1@global

This command sets ruby to selected default permanently. All new terminals will use your default Ruby. Also you don't mention anything about gemset, so I presume global would exist if you didn't mess up your setup.

Comment: that command game me a correct message, however when I ran 'rails c' again, it didn't know what rails was. so it didn't work. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 0):

This solved it:

I added `rvm use --default` to the machine's ~/.bashrc file.